# Laravel changes my CSRF token when I make quick ajax requests to the server

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, csrf, csrf-token

I know how to use Laravel CSRF tokens in forms and ajax requests.

I can make a one-time ajax request and it works.

But if I make two ajax POST requests really quickly (like by clicking a button two times fast), Laravel changes my CSRF token, so the second request fails.  And the form on the page would then fail too.

If I click the button once every second or so, it all works fine.  Only fast, or maybe concurrent requests, change the CSRF token.

Any ideas?

I'm using Laravel 8.21.0

Comment: Sounds like it may be getting regenerated with each call

Comment: Maybe try to add a loader after you click the button, or disable it

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was running `Auth::login(user)` to log in a user inside our middleware on every page request.  Turns out Laravel doesn't like that.

So now I only call that once, when the user actually logs in.

Seems to work now.